# Read access violation on dumping UAV buffer contents

Tags: directx, hlsl, direct3d, compute-shader

I'm trying to modify an existing example from Frank Luna's Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11. The compute shader code originally takes two structured buffers via SRVs and adds them and writes them into a structured buffer via UAV. Instead, I'd like to load from one raw buffer and store directly into another raw buffer, both via UAV.

```
// declare buffers and views
ID3D11Buffer* mInputBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* mOutputBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* mOutputDebugBuffer;
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* mInputUAV;
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* mOutputUAV;

// fill vector of DWORDs
UINT mNumElements = 256;
std::vector<DWORD> inputData(mNumElements);
for (int i = 0; i < mNumElements; ++i)
{
    inputData[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

// buffer description
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * mNumElements;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(DWORD);
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_ALLOW_RAW_VIEWS; // allow raw data

// Fill buffer with vector data
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vinitDataInput;
vinitDataInput.pSysMem = &inputData[0];

// create buffers
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &vinitDataInput, &mInputBuffer));
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, 0, &mOutputBuffer));

// create buffer to store output transferred from GPU to CPU
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC debugOutputDesc;
ZeroMemory(&debugOutputDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
debugOutputDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
debugOutputDesc.BindFlags = 0;
debugOutputDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, 0, &mOutputDebugBuffer));

// UAV description
D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC uavDesc;
uavDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS; # DWORD
uavDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
uavDesc.Buffer.FirstElement = 0;
uavDesc.Buffer.Flags = D3D11_BUFFER_UAV_FLAG_RAW; // allow raw data
uavDesc.Buffer.NumElements = mNumElements;

// create views
md3dDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(mInputBuffer, &uavDesc, &mInputUAV);
md3dDevice->CreateUnorderedAccessView(mOutputBuffer, &uavDesc, &mOutputUAV);

// excerpt from Effect class
ID3DX11EffectUnorderedAccessViewVariable* Input;
ID3DX11EffectUnorderedAccessViewVariable* Output;
void SetInput(ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* uav) { Input->SetUnorderedAccessView(uav); }
void SetOutput(ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* uav) { Output->SetUnorderedAccessView(uav); }
Input = mFX->GetVariableByName("gInput")->AsUnorderedAccessView();
Output = mFX->GetVariableByName("gOutput")->AsUnorderedAccessView();
// end of excerpt from Effect class

// bind UAVs
Effects::VecAddFX->SetInput(mInputUAV);
Effects::VecAddFX->SetOutput(mOutputUAV);

// dispatch one TG
Effects::VecAddFX->VecAddTech->GetDesc( &techDesc );
for(UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p)
{
    ID3DX11EffectPass* pass = Effects::VecAddFX->VecAddTech->GetPassByIndex(p);
    pass->Apply(0, md3dImmediateContext);

    md3dImmediateContext->Dispatch(1, 1, 1);
}

// disable compute shader
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* nullSRV[1] = { 0 };
md3dImmediateContext->CSSetShaderResources( 0, 1, nullSRV );
ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* nullUAV[1] = { 0 };
md3dImmediateContext->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews( 0, 1, nullUAV, 0 );
md3dImmediateContext->CSSetShader(0, 0, 0);

// open results file
std::ofstream fout;
fout.open("results.txt", std::ios_base::app);

// copy output buffer to debug buffer
md3dImmediateContext->CopyResource(mOutputDebugBuffer, mOutputBuffer);

// map data
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedData; 
md3dImmediateContext->Map(mOutputDebugBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedData);

// cast to DWORD and write to file
DWORD* dataView = reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(mappedData.pData);
for (int i = 0; i < mNumElements; ++i)
{
    fout << std::hex << dataView[i] << std::endl;
}

md3dImmediateContext->Unmap(mOutputDebugBuffer, 0);

fout.close();
```

The shader is:

```
RWByteAddressBuffer gInput;
RWByteAddressBuffer gOutput;

[numthreads(256, 1, 1)]
void CS(int3 dtid : SV_DispatchThreadID, int3 tgid : SV_GroupThreadID)
{
    uint inData = gInput.Load(tgid.x);
    gOutput.Store(tgid.x, inData);
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error from `fout << std::hex << dataView[i] << std::endl;`.

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
dataView was 0x1110112.
```

In the Autos window, dataView's value is `0x00000000 {???}` and it indicates `<Unable to read memory>`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don’t think this solves your error, but still I think you need to do `uint inData = gInput.Load(dtid.x);
    gOutput.Store(dtid.x, inData);` (use `dtid` as index instead of `tgid`) if you want to copy the whole buffer. Otherwise, you’ll have 256 threads trying to copy the same location.

Comment: You must check the result of any Direct3D function that returns an ``HRESULT`` for failure using ``SUCCEEDED`` or ``FAILED``, or use a fast-fail solution like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed). If it was safe at runtime to ignore a failure, it would return ``void``. I see you have a few ``HR`` macros which do the old-school version of this, but not at every potential failure point.

Comment: I've made the suggested changes and  `HR(md3dImmediateContext->Map(mOutputDebugBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedData));` was the issue. Turns out I did not define the buffer description for mOutputDebugBuffer correctly. I now have a new issue: the results.txt file always shows a valid value for the first quarter of elements but the remainder is 0s. It seems that the rest of the elements will populate with valid values only if I set the numthreads to 4 times mNumElements. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chuck's suggestion, I narrowed down the read access violation issue to:

```
// create buffer to store output transferred from GPU to CPU
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC debugOutputDesc;
ZeroMemory(&debugOutputDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));
debugOutputDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
debugOutputDesc.BindFlags = 0;
debugOutputDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, 0, &mOutputDebugBuffer));
```

I created a debugOutputDesc but I used bufferDesc during CreateBuffer. The correct code should be:

```
// Create a system memory version of the buffer to read the results back from.
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
HR(md3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, 0, &mOutputDebugBuffer));
```